# Error while launching Wakfu

Tags: 12.04, java

I installed Wakfu on my Ubuntu 12.04 from the source downloaded from the game website.

But while opening it the following error came up:

```
 '/opt/ankama/Wakfu/Wakfu' 
The archive /opt/ankama/Wakfu/core.jar does not exist.
```

I also installed sun java. What should I do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the java folder into `/opt/ankama/Wakfu` folder and run wakfu from the menu and the application will open.